# The most efficient method of performing a large number of similar SELECT queries on PostgreSQL?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2, rdbms

I have a set of large tables with many records each. I'm writing a Python program that `SELECT`s a large number of records from these tables, based on the value of multiple columns on those records.

Essentially, these are going to be lots of queries of the form:

```
SELECT <some columns> FROM <some table> WHERE <column1=val1 AND column2=val2...>
```

Each table has a different set of columns, but otherwise the `SELECT` formula above holds.

By default, I was going to just run all these queries through the `psycopg2` PostgreSQL database driver, each as a separate query. But I'm wondering if there's a more efficient way of going about it, given that there will be a very large number of such queries - thousands or more.

Comment: If your tables have the same columns, there is something wrong with your data model.  In general, you want only one table for a given set of columns.  It makes queries like this much simpler.

Comment: Tables have _columns_, not fields.

Comment: @GordonLinoff the different tables have different sets of columns. I will see if I can edit my question to make that clearer.

Comment: If you have those queries coming in one by one, then there is not much you can do, except for optimizing your queries, using indexes, partitioning if needed etc. If you are selecting multiple records in bulk, however, there are options: main idea is to create temporary query tables based on similar queries (having the same columns) and performing `JOINs` on those filter tables - this might speed up your queries significantly, depending on the queries you have.

Comment: @SergeyKudriavtsev these queries are generated by the program, in bulk. So your idea might work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `SELECT` list entries are the same for all queries (the same number of entries and the same data types), you can use `UNION ALL` to combine several such queries. This won't reduce the amount of work for the database, but it will reduce the number of client-server round trips. This can be a huge improvement, because for short queries network latency is often the dominant cost.

If all your queries have different `SELECT` lists, there is nothing you can do.

Comment: Different tables have different column sets, so it seems I can't `UNION ALL` queries across tables. However, it would appear I can use this method to bunch together all the queries that target each table. These can still be thousands of queries per table, so that can be a nice efficiency gain.

Comment: Yes, that should work. With some more effort you can use a `WHERE` condition like `WHERE (col1, col2) IN ((val1, val2), (val3, val4), ...)`. With the right index that could be a winner.